# Gathering postgres pids/backends from pg_stat_activity returns constant result in one session

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Within one session with isolation level `READ_COMMITTED` the list of active pids from `pg_stat_activity` is gathered only once and next tries return the same results. Does anyone can explain why?

Script to reproduce that phenomenon:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

pg_uri = 'postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/test'


def get_session():
    bind = create_engine(pg_uri, poolclass=NullPool, echo=False, isolation_level="READ_COMMITTED")
    session_class = sessionmaker(bind=bind)
    return session_class()

def pg_sleep():
    get_session().execute('select pg_sleep(3)')


def show_backends(session, prefix):
    backends = session.execute("SELECT pid, query FROM pg_stat_activity where state = 'active';").fetchall()
    print ("%s found processes:" % prefix)
    for backend in backends:
        print("%s: %s %s" % (prefix, backend[0], backend[1][:32]))


def spawn_backend():
    import threading
    print("spawning backend")
    threading.Thread(None, target=pg_sleep).start()
    show_backends(get_session(), 'thread')


session = get_session()
for tries in range(3):
   spawn_backend()
   time.sleep(1)
   show_backends(session, '-main-')
```

I'm using:

```
postgresql-9.6
Python 2.7.12
SQLAlchemy 1.1.12
```

Comment: NOTE: the result comes from time when it was invoked first time, not from time when session was opened and it's not cached by `sqlalchemy` as setting `echo=True` shows that query is issued to `postgres`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs about [monitoring stats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html) says that:

> Another important point is that when a server process is asked to display any of these statistics, it first fetches the most recent report emitted by the collector process and then continues to use this snapshot for all statistical views and functions until the end of its current transaction. So the statistics will show static information as long as you continue the current transaction. Similarly, information about the current queries of all sessions is collected when any such information is first requested within a transaction, and the same information will be displayed throughout the transaction. This is a feature, not a bug, because it allows you to perform several queries on the statistics and correlate the results without worrying that the numbers are changing underneath you. But if you want to see new results with each query, be sure to do the queries outside any transaction block. Alternatively, you can invoke pg_stat_clear_snapshot(), which will discard the current transaction's statistics snapshot (if any). The next use of statistical information will cause a new snapshot to be fetched.

Please, consider using `pg_stat_clear_snapshot` in your code.